# Python Beautiful Soup: Problem getting the text of an class element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the text "(0 26 02) 1 68 23" of this element:

```
<div class="unmasked">
(0 26 02) 1 68 23
<br>
</div>

result.select(".unmasked")[0].text
```

gives me the right element, but the .text is empty.

Is there a way to get the value?

Comment: Do you need to index it with `[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc="""
<div class="unmasked">
(0 26 02) 1 68 23
<br>
</div>

"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
t = soup.select(".unmasked")[0].text
print(t)
```

output:

```
(0 26 02) 1 68 23
```

Comment: Thanks. Problem was, that the value is generated via script during site loading. In browser I see it, in my request not. Have to use pyypeteer to mimic the browser behaviour.

Comment: Yes, data is loaded dynamically by javascript and to grab data/value you have to use automation tool something like pyypeteer  or selenium.